# What, exactly, is meant by  "Anschluss" in politics?

Tags: history, meaning-in-context

In its "usual" usage in politics, it refers to the (forced) union of Germany and Austria in 1938.

And a literal translation of the word might be "closing."

Can the term be used to refer to a "merger of equals," e.g. of Poland and Lithuania around 1550? Or does it have the connotations of an "unequal" match, with one party swallowing up the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In history and politics**, it's not an Anschluss, it is *the* "Anschluss".

Literally, the word means connection or the making of a connection. It was used by the Nazis as [a euphemism to describe the merger of Austria into Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss) (not as a merger of equals, but as a "homecoming" of sorts).

Usage of this word in the context of history and politics is exclusive for this one incident, which is why I put a definite article instead of an indefinite one. It is also advisable to put the term in quotation marks, as I did, to show that you are using Nazi terminology and distance yourself from it.

**In all other contexts**, the word has no negative connotation and is used often in its literal sense.

Of course, the word can be used to suggest a parallel to the "Anschluss" of Austria in 1938 even in other contexts, but that would be poor taste and the jibe might also go unnoticed. For instance, calling the wedding of two people an "Anschluss" would suggest that one party would give up sovereignty and submit to the whims of the other - not a nice thing to say, and not a nice way to say it.

Comment: "In all other contexts, the word has no negative connotation and is used often in its literal sense." - as someone who doesn't speak German, I was once surprised to see the word in an instruction manual. Another case of a word being mundane in German but having a specific meaning to English-speakers is [Zyklon](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/2233890.stm), which Siemens used for an oven (a gas oven, no less)!

Comment: @Andrew, I think the Zyklon naming by Siemens was a blooper. No one in their right mind would do that. Anschluss, however, is a perfectly normal word meaning attachment, connection, link. Nobody would take note if you were to connect your oven to a Gas-Anschluss (though there are more correct and more beautiful ways to say this, the verb *anschließen* would probably feature in all of them).

Comment: I strongly agree with this answer: The German reunification for example would never be called an "Anschluss", even if the term would fit perfectly the facts (eastern Germany joined the west instead of a real merge of the two "Germanys").

+1 also for the widespread usage of "Anschluss" in other contexts: "im Anschluss an" (after), "den Anschluss verpassen" (to stay behind), "Anschluss suchen" (trying to make friends) are examples of non-literal use.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using quotation marks around "Anschluß". Either you find the word appropriate, then you use it, or you don't, then use something else. Negative connotations are always in your mind, not in the word.

Comment: @userunknown: I would not use quotation marks in other contexts, but it is advisable to use them when talking about the forced unification of 1938, just as it is when using words such as "Reichskristallnacht" etc. - to distance yourself from the euphemism.

Comment: I don't see an euphemism in "Anschluss" - it is just a term like "Wiedervereinigung".

Comment: @userunknown: It might seem so, but it is not. The "Anschluss" was an annexion, not a voluntary link-up. To prevent exactly the kind of honest mistake you just made (thhinking this is just a harmless ordinary word instead of a term made up by propaganda to distort the truth), we put the word in quotation marks when using it as a technical term with the meaning "the unification of Germany and Austria in 1938". See also the [German Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss_Österreichs), where they also put quotes around the term.

Comment: Addendum: See also [this discussion on Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:Anschluss_Österreichs#.E2.80.9EAnschluss.E2.80.9C_oder_Anschluss.3F).

Comment: Well - the term "Anschluss" does not carry the meaning of "voluntary" - the angeschlossene Part is passive in this construct. Your term "unification" is in contrast open to an symetric interpretation which is not present in "Anschluss". And funnily, if you look up "Annexion" you'll find "Anschluss", so your claim is a contradictio in adjecto.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2134/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-fzwo)

Comment: Was war es denn, wenn es kein Anschluss war? Oder: In welcher Hinsicht war es kein Anschluss? Nur, weil die Nazis ein Wort benutzt haben wird es ja nicht automatisch zum Euphemismus.

Comment: Schrieb ich doch schon: Eine Annexion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has the connotation of a bigger country or more powerful state swallowing up the smaller one, though it suggests the voluntary merge of two states. *Anschluss* as the noun of the verb *anschließen* can have many meanings of which *sich etw. anschließen* as in *to join sth.* is the most suitable here.

If I wanted to express a "merging of equals" I'd rather use the noun *Vereinigung* which means *[re]union* or alternatively the German noun *Union* as in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polen-Litauen).

Comment: IMHO the word *Anschluss* is strongly connected to the occupation and annexation of Austria into Nazi Germany. Using this word in another context is, let's put it this way, *dangerous*.

Comment: @splattne: I disagree with the second part: Using the word in other contexts is absolutely OK, but using it in the same context for other unifications of countries (such as east and west Germany) is "dangerous", as you say, that is, it is suggesting parallels to what happened in 1938.

Comment: Actually, the context of my question was "social." In my (German-American) circles, someone used the term to describe a relationship in which the two parties were 24 years apart in age. One interpretation would be a prediction that they would make a "connection" (marriage). The other interpretation would be the "grossly unequal" part. And I don't dare ask any of the three parties what this meant.

Comment: @Tom: If somebody called a potential marriage an "Anschluss", that would probably be a jibe playing with the political meaning (and as such, bad taste, IMHO). I can't imagine a native german speaker calling a marriage or other civil union an Anschluss. One could call it a Zusammenschluss. (Somebody unaware of the connotation might clumsily refer to an unequal merger of companies or clubs as an Anschluss of the smaller one to the larger one)

Comment: @Tom I edited my answer to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Ein Staat/Teil/Partner kann sich einem anderen anschließen, oder von diesem zum Anschluß gezwungen werden. Die Freiwilligkeit oder der Zwang sind nicht Teil des Begriffs "Anschluß", wie auch die Größenverhältnisse unbedeutend sind. `Ringo Starr schloß sich den Beatles an` (freiwillig, soweit wir wissen). `Ich schließe das Diskettenlaufwerk an den PC an.` aber auch: `Ich schließe den PC an ein externes Diskettenlaufwerk an.` Anschluss ist im Alltag ein so gängiges Wort, dass selbst die Verwendung im Zusammenhang mit territorialen Mächten unbefangen erlebt werden kann.

Comment: @userunknown Ich stimme dir zu, was die Freiwilligkeit angeht, bin aber der Meinung, das die Größenverhältnisse durchaus eine Rolle spielen. Wenn Personen einer Gruppe beitreten, dann spricht man von "sich anschließen". Gründen zwei Personen eine Gruppe ist Anschluss nicht der richtige Begriff. So wird meiner Meinung nach der Begriff auch im Bezug auf Staaten verwendet.

Comment: Ein erfahrener Bergsteiger will wg. des schlechten Wetters umkehren, statt den Protobolja zu besteigen. Eine Gruppe Touristen schließt sich ihm an. Wo ist das Problem?

Comment: @userunknwon Ein gutes Beispiel, zugegeben. Trotzdem empfinde ich das Beispiel `Ich schließe den PC an ein externes Diskettenlaufwerk an.` zumindest als seltsam, obwohl verständlich ist, was gemeint ist. Bei Staaten sagt man wohl immer dann `X schließt sich Y` an, wenn der Zusammenschluss später den Namen und die Organisationsstruktur von Y trägt. Y könnte dabei auch kleiner oder weniger mächtig als X sein, auch wenn mir ein solcher Fall in der Geschichte nicht bekannt ist.